# 8088 assembly checksum implementation

Tags: assembly, checksum

The following 8088/8086 assembly program tests the modular-sum checksum of a block of data. I suspect it could be tighter; can anyone do it in fewer bytes?

```
31        xor        ax,ax          ; zero the sum
c0
bb        mov        bx,2000h        ; count 8kb of ROM
00
20
4b        dec        bx             ; start at the top
02        add        al,[bx]        ; add the current byte to the total
07
85        test       bx,bx          ; see if we're at the bottom yet
db
75        jnz        -7             ; loop while not done
f9
84        test       al,al          ; sum should be 0
c0
74        jz         1              ; if sum is good, continue with program
01
f4        hlt                       ; if sum is bad, stop
```

Comment: If that is intended to check 8k, shouldn't that be `2000h` instead of just `2000`?  Also, you could rework the code to use the flags that get set by `dec` to figure out if you should keep looping rather than doing `test`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I've been hand-coding the byte-stream. I'll add an `h` it to make it clearer. As for using the flags affected by `dec`, I was under the impression the `add` operation following it would mangle them. I also thought of re-ordering the `dec` and the `add`, but then the 0000 byte is skipped, so I would have to have another two bytes after the loop anyway, to add it on. (Actually I think I like that better anyway, since it makes the loop tighter).

Comment: Why do you have to do `cld`?  Is there unknown code that executes before this that has a habit of changing and not restoring this?  I'd certainly expect the power-on default for any 8086 chip to be cld.

Comment: It's true that the flags are cleared after CPU reset. I guess I've been burned too many times by assuming state. Am I being too cautious?

Comment: I'd say not.  Code like this is often reused and having `cld` versus omitting it means that you trade off a single byte for the potential future pain of having things run just fine *most* of the time until some other function is called that changes the direction flag before this code is invoked.  Good luck untangling that runtime nightmare.  I'd rather pay the price for the byte and the additional clarity, but that's just me.

Comment: Too bad we can't index-address on CX; that would let us remove the LODSB, and just use ADD directly.

Comment: Please do not modify the question to reflect changes made in response to answers or comments. Those changes would actually make the answers invalid. This is site policy. If you want a review of your updated code, you have to ask a new question.

Comment: In addition to Donald.McLean. Please rollback to rev6. And please look at *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it would be useful to preserve the time sequence of improvements in the top post, so people could see it evolve. The vote ordering could lose that dimension.

Comment: Ok, I rolled it back to the revision with the CLD in it. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I've rolled it back even further, to Rev 3, which was the last revision to be purely about your original code. We are quite strict here on Code Review about asking one question per question; otherwise the Q&A gets messy and confusing.

Comment: understood......

Comment: "Am I being too cautious?" - I'd say it depends on your environment.  If you can feel confident about the code that is being executed before you and are desperate for that 1 more byte...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not absolutely certain (I haven't run it through an assembler or checked against an instruction chart), but I *believe* this may be a byte shorter:

```
    xor dl, dl    
    xor si, si    
    mov cx, 2000h         
again:
    lodsb       ; load value, increment SI
    add dl, al  ; set z flag based on result of addition
    loop again  ; decrement CX, jump if NZ, *without* affecting flags

    jz good     ; Z flag still has result of addition above
    hlt
good:
```

Comment: Are you sure about that comma after `loop`?

Comment: This might need a `cld` instruction to assure that `lodsb` increments `SI`.

Comment: @Edward: well, it should probably at least have a comment saying that it assumes the D flag is clear (but unless otherwise specified, that *is* normally a pretty safe assumption).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Oops. Yes, at least with most assemblers that would be wrong.

Comment: I think it's actually _two_ bytes shorter than the original, and a byte shorter than David's modification, but that's without the `cld`.

Comment: Wouldn't `xor dl, dl` be 1 byte shorter?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Oops--yes, that was what was really intended. Thanks.

Comment: In 16-bit mode, `xor dl, dl` and `xor dx, dx` are both 2 bytes. And yes, this is 2 bytes shorter than original code (17 vs. 15 bytes). But more importantly, it is ~60 cycles instead of ~64. (On the 8088, cycle counting can actually be somewhat meaningful.) The string instruction is a *big* perf win, since it's only 1 byte, making it more likely that the 8088's anemic 4-byte buffer will be kept filled while running that loop. But the perf will still be terrible because of all the branching... Each time `LOOP` is taken, it costs ~17 cycles! That's a lot of wasted perf in the inner loop. :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no real way to fix that. You can't use a `REP` prefix on `LODSB` because you need to do some work in between. (In fact, this is why `REP LODSB` is essentially worthless.) You could trade size for speed by unrolling the loop. Normally, trading size for speed on the 8088 doesn't make sense because of its anemic buffer, but loop unrolling can be an exception. I would *strongly* recommend it here. Also, if you want to assume success, reverse the direction of `jz good` so that you fall through in the common case. Put `HLT` at the very end and branch to it. (cc @James)

Comment: Oh! One thing you *could* do as an alternative to unrolling is use `LODSW` instead of `LODSB`. They are both 1-byte and they both take ~16 cycles (nominal) on the 8088. This effectively unrolls the loop by 2, without bloating the code much at all. So this way, inside `again`, you'd have: `lodsw`+`add dl, al`+`add dl, ah`+`loop again`.

Comment: @CodyGray: Experience shows that other than a handful of slow instructions (e.g., DIV/IDIV) an 8088 is *almost* always bottlenecked by instruction fetching, so most of the time you're best off just keeping your code as small as possible.

Comment: That's true, Jerry, except in the case of branching, were a taken branch always clears the buffer, so you get the penalty of the branch *plus* the penalty of more instruction fetches. That's why unrolling a loop makes sense, and why `LODSW` seems like the best alternative to me because it has an extremely minor effect on the code size while cutting in *half* the number of taken branches. Of course, I could be wrong, as this is all theoretical. I didn't get out my 8088 to benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this version (which incorporates suggestions from David Wohlferd in the comments) is one byte shorter:

```
a0      mov     al,[0000h]      ; the loop skips byte 0000, so add it here
00
00
bb      mov     bx,1fffh        ; count 8kb of ROM
ff
1f
02      add     al,[bx]         ; add current byte to the total, top->bottom
07
4b      dec     bx
75      jnz     -5              ; loop while not done
fb
84      test    al,al           ; sum should be 0
c0
74      jz      1               ; if sum is good, continue with program
01
f4      hlt                     ; if sum is bad, stop
```

Comment: I was going to recommend using `xor al, al` to clear the register (some processors optimize for that), but I wonder if `mov al, ds:1fff` would work?  I suspect it wouldn't save you (or cost you) any bytes, but it would reduce the number of loops needed by 1 (`mov bx, 1ffeh`).

Comment: The 8088 certainly doesn't optimize for XOR to clear registers. It doesn't have register renaming, and doesn't need to break any dependencies. It isn't nearly that complicated of a chip. :-) Of course, XOR to clear a register is still preferable over MOV because it is 1 byte shorter! And reducing the code size, as you appear to already know, is a big deal when optimizing for the 8088. (And 386SX.)

Comment: By the way, just as a code style thing, I would strongly encourage you to use *labels* as branch targets, rather than hard-coding numerical offsets. Not only does this make the code easier to read at a glance, without having to count bytes, but the numerical offsets are kind of ambiguous, since many assemblers tend to represent them differently than Intel's documentation does. It doesn't change the size of the code or anything to use labels; the assembler will generate identical code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm still learning assembly language, and I haven't actually had to use an assembler yet. I just type the bytecodes directly into a file with a hex editor. I'm getting pretty good at reading the raw hex.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well then you are more hardcore than me. :-) Do consider using an assembler and making your life easier. Writing quality, readable assembly code is hard enough. Doing it with a hex editor is just masochism. On retro machines, MASM and TASM are excellent options, usually available on "abandonware" sites. I don't personally see any ethical problems with that, *especially* with MASM if you own a modern license for a Microsoft development product like Visual Studio. If you prefer free software, NASM and YASM are also excellent choices, and you can do retro-dev from a modern box.